Creating module only for integration tests
Lets say i have 3 modules:

core-module - core module for project
communication-api - api module exposing API's for communication services
communication-msg-impl - concrete implementation for communication-api ( one of few )

Now core-module has dependency to communication-api in base, when using this core-module for concrete project, user adds dependency to one of communication-api's implementations to the project.
communication-msg-impl has dependency to communication-api
I want to create test that tests whole flow when core-module uses communication-msg-impl, however this test would need to be in module-core package, since it requires functionality from the module, but that would mean i need to add dependency to communication-msg-impl to it. Which is not wanted behavior.
Is it good practice to create whole different module just for these integration tests?
I can have multiple communication-msg-impl modules ( each for different implementation) so it would mean i would need to create new "testing" module for each implementation.
Thanks for answers


I want to create test that tests whole flow when core-module uses
communication-msg-impl, however this test would need to be in
module-core package, since it requires functionality from the module

That's not necessarily true, you could put the tests that depend on communication-msg-impl in the communication-msg-impl module and add core-module as a <scope>test<scope> dependency to communication-msg-impl. Since it's only a test dependency the communication-msg-impl jar won't have a dependency on core-module.

Is it good practice to create whole different module just for these integration tests?

This is also an acceptable solution. If you have many impl modules it makes sense to create an integration-test module which depends on all of the impl modules as well as core-module
